# android. copy aar file from each module to assets folder

Tags: android, gradle, copy, assets

project has following structure:

modules:

build.gradle
**app**
....assets
....build.gradle
**core**
....build/outputs/aar/core-release.aar (*is creating during gradle build*)
**data**
....build/outputs/aar/data-release.aar (*is creating during gradle build*)

I need to copy generated aars into assets folder

I'm trying to copy it somehow but nothing happens

in file **app**/build.gradle

```
...
task copyAarsToAssets(type: Copy) {
    from 'core/build/outputs/aar'
    into 'assets'
}
project.afterEvaluate {
    prepareDebugDependencies.dependsOn('copyAarsToAssets')
}
...
```

Is it possible to copy aars in assets folder? And how can I do this?